# Calling functions in an SQL statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a function called strip_tags defined in postgreSQL which strips out HTML tags in a given string.(I know trying to strip out html tags at db level is frowned upon, but i have to do this).

I want to extract some news from my db therefore I am executing a query:

```
SELECT description FROM news WHERE description ilike '%apple%'
```

Data in the description column is a mixture of html and text and i want to strip the html and then search if it matches '%apple%' or not! somewhat like:

```
SELECT description FROM news WHERE (select strip_tags(description)) ilike '%apple%'
```

Is this possible in postgreSQL? I tried executing this query but it dint work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function in your `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT description 
FROM news 
WHERE strip_tags(description) ilike '%apple%'
```